# Replace key references by corresponding values in dict values

Tags: python, dictionary

In the following dictionary, a user can refer to a key as a variable for defining another value:

```
d = {'a_key': 'a_value', 'b_key': 'a_key+1'}
```

I have to replace these references by the corresponding values, in order to obtain this desired output:

```
d = {'a_key': 'a_value', 'b_key': 'a_value+1'}
```

I thought it would be easy, but this one drives crazy since a few hours. I got to this code:

```
for k in d.keys():
    print("key: " + k)
    print("value: " + d[k])
    for v in d.values():
        print("value_before: " + v)
        v = v.replace(k, d[k])
        print("value_after: " + v)
print(d)
```

The output is:

```
key: a_key
value: a_value
value_before: a_value
value_after: a_value
value_before: a_key+1
value_after: a_value+1
key: b_key
value: a_key+1        # WHY??
value_before: a_value
value_after: a_value
value_before: a_key+1
value_after: a_key+1
{'a_key': 'a_value', 'b_key': 'a_key+1'}
```

As we see, the first iteration seems to do the job, before it is cancelled by the second one. I just don't unserstand why. I also tried to adapt the very specific answers to that question: [Replace values in dict if value of another key within a nested dict is found in value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435546/replace-values-in-dict-if-value-of-another-key-within-a-nested-dict-is-found-in), but to no avail. I'm looking for a general answer to: how to get the desired output?

From a theoretic point of view, I would also like to understand why the `"b_value"` is reset to `a_key+1`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying temporary variable `v` but you are not placing the modified values back in the dictionary.

Try replacing :

```
for v in d.values():
    v = v.replace(k, d[k])
```

with:

```
for r,v in d.items():
    d[r] = v.replace(k, d[k])
```